# CAPL script to produce a Bus off on can Network

Tags: can-bus, capl

Actually I am trying to produce a BUS off using CAPL predefined functions.

I am sending error frame using  this function canOutputErrorFrame(can1.errorframe,8,0) repetitively so the counter reach 255 , but I saw that the network doesn't change its state to Bus off. Please does anyone work on this before?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
canConfigureBusOff(1, msg id here, 1); // enable disturbance
canConfigureBusOff(1, msg id here, 0); // disable disturbance
```